# ngx-bootstrap multilist carousel not working in angular 10

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular10

I am implementing a multi-list carousel using `"ngx-bootstrap": "6.0.0",` but it looks like it does not work in `angular: 10.0.2`. I also tried with `ngx-bootstrap: 6.0.0`, it also did not work

It only shows one slide [first image] and a placeholder for the rest of the images. like if `itemsPerSlide` is 3, it only shows 1 image and placeholder for 2 images.

Component code

```
@ViewChild(CarouselComponent) myCarousel: CarouselComponent;
  loopcomplete = true;
  slidesChangeMessage;
  itemsPerSlide = 3;
  singleSlideOffset = true;
  noWrap = true;
  activeRange = 0;

  slides = [
    {image: 'assets/slides/1.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/2.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/3.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/4.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/5.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/6.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/7.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/8.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/9.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/10.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/11.jpeg'},
    {image: 'assets/slides/12.jpeg'},
  ];
```

HTML code

```
<div>
  <carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide"
            [singleSlideOffset]="singleSlideOffset"
            [noWrap]="!noWrap"
            [interval]="false"
            [startFromIndex]="0"
            (slideRangeChange)="onSlideRangeChange($event)">
    <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index">
      <img [src]="slide.image" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
      </div>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a bug in carousel.
I see, that similar issue was reported in https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5879 , so, hope to take a look at it in the nearest future. Anyway, I will share any info about fixes there

### [Workaround](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5879#issuecomment-673895120) from linked issue above:

When inspecting the carousel elements css, notice that `.carousel-item` class has `margin-right` set to `-100%`

To fix this, add this css:

```
.carousel-item {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to v6.0.0 which is Angular v9.x & v10.x compatible!

Comment: did not work for me, I updated the questions with code

Answer (score 0):

You should update your ngx-bootstrap to version 6. Please check compatibility on their npm package.

[image: NGX-BOOTSTRAP Compatibility]

Comment: did not work for me, I updated the questions with code

Answer (score 0):

Return to version 4.0.0 of Bootstrap. It worked for me.

It's not working with version 4.5.0.